# KnockoutJS and mapping plugin specific logic on data update using template afterrender

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

This is kind of a two part problem.

First, I'm using an afterrender on my template binding to accomplish an action each time the template renders new data. That works correctly...except it works too correctly. It doesn't fire unless data is added, or removed.

Second, to combat the first "issue" I figured I needed to write a custom "update" and detect if the data has changed. Which again makes sense, however I realized that the update function in the mapping also follows that "only run if data is added or removed" idea.

So then I figured I needed to make an update around one specific property of the mapping model like:

```
var dataMappingOptions = {
    key: function(data) {
        return data.id;        
    },
    create: function(options) {
        return new Person(options.data);
    },
    update: function(options) {
        // if first changed, doSomething();
        return options.target;
    },
    'first': {
        update: function(options) {
            // if first changed, doSomething();
            return options.target.first;
        }
    }   
};
```

But that just turns into a whole mess, and doesn't even work.

Here is the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/farina/bVPwM/10/) if you want to check it out.

Long story short, I'm sure that there must be a way to subscribe to a property as it's being updated? I guess maybe you just have to make computed observables? I'm going to toss this out there and see if [Ryan](http://www.knockmeout.net/) wants to teach me as he has so many times already :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can maybe explain if there is something different that you are trying to accomplish, but here is how I would approach it:

I would use a manual subscription to `firstName` and perform my action there.  I would set up this subscription in your `Person` constructor.

Something like:

```
var Person = function(data) {
    this.id = data.id;
    this.first = ko.observable(data.first);
    this.last = ko.observable(data.last);
    this.full = ko.computed(function() {
        return this.first() + " " + this.last();
    }, this);    
    this.first.subscribe(function(newValue) {
         alert(this.full() + " had his/her first name changed");
    }, this);        
};
```

Would be like this sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/EDC7q/

Would this be sufficient?  What type of action do you want to take when the value changes?

Comment: I'm performing a UI action which only needs to run on data change. Unfortunately afterrender doesn't fire on data update, only add and remove. What is the difference between subscribe and computed?

Comment: A subscription is specific to a single observable and it does not create additional dependencies when it is being evaluated.

Comment: Is there a way I can subscribe after Knockout has rendered the UI? I've got situation where I'm using jQuery QuickSand to render the updated UI from a hidden KO template. What happens with subscribe is that the UI update is called before the KO template is updated.

Comment: I think that you would either want to look at using a custom binding or potentially look at performing your action in a `setTimeout(yourAction, 0);`

Comment: I went with the setTimeout earlier. I figured that there might be some kind of way to tap into the rendering engine...but I guess that's not possible. Thanks again!